# DataGridView doesn't add new table when DataMember of BindingSource is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am making a form that allows editing of the database within the application. A ListBox has all the tables (I added the names of the tables manually) and when clicked on the DataGridView should change to that table.

However, when I change the `DataMember` property of the BindingSource the grid is bound to, is shows the columns of the original table, but there are no records. The `BindingSource`'s `DataSource` is my database's dataset.
When I click back on the original table it displays the data of that table.

This is the code I tried:

```
private void lstTables_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wCAsystemdbDataSetBindingSource.DataMember = lstTables.Text;
}
```

Comment: What is the DataSource of the BindingSource? How did you fill the ListBox? Add these details to the body of the question, not in a comment -- Don't get the Text of LIstBox, get the text associated to its `DisplayMember`, as in `string someText = lstTables.GetItemText(lstTables.SelectedItem);`

Comment: Hi, I added what you said. Also that alternative code didn't work.

Comment: What I posted is **only** related to retrieving the value of an Item, not related to the binding functionality itself -- You need to specify what's already been asked. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74628710/edit) your question to add these details (which means exactly the code you have used to setup the bindings)